# Referencing the class in it self in Class method

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to access the class methods inside the class it self. I know you could use **self** keyword in a class instance like so:

```
class InstanceClass {
    var testProperty = "testing"

    func testMathod() {
       print(self.testProperty)
    }
}

// initiate like so
let newInstance = InstanceClass()
newInstance.testMathod() // result testing
```

What's the keyword for accessing class in static property in below example:

```
class BaseClass {

  static let testProperty = "test"

  class func printProperty () {
      // here I want to access testProperty  
  }
}
```

I aware that I could do BaseClass.testProperty in above example but I want to keep it abstract.

I have Swift 2.11 running.

Comment: " I want to keep it abstract" can you please explain more about this?

Comment: Consider this example:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/46ff24e7adbf95d151fe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.. **self** keyword works with Class Methods also.

Example:

```
class BaseClass {

   class var testProperty: String {
      return "Original Word"
   }


   static func printTestPropery() {
      print(self.testProperty)
   }

}

class ChildClass: BaseClass {
  override class var testProperty: String {
    return "Modified Word"
  }
}


ChildClass.printTestPropery() // prints "Modified Word"
```

Answer (score 0):

I find Swift to be a little inconsistent for this but here is how you access static class properties from various scopes:

```
class BaseClass 
{
  static let testProperty = "test2"

  // access class property from class function
  class func printProperty() 
  {
      print( testProperty )  
  }

  // access class property from instance function
  func printClassProperty()
  {
     print(BaseClass.testProperty)
     print(self.dynamicType.testProperty)
  }
}

protocol PrintMe:class
{
   static var testProperty:String { get }
}

extension BaseClass:PrintMe {}

extension PrintMe
{
   // access from a class protocol can use Self for the class
   func printFromProtocol()
   {
      print(Self.testProperty)
   }
}
```